# How to integrate Apex PMD with husky and lint-staged?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code, ide, pmd

I am currently working on the IDE setup for a SFDX project. In my opinion the process for ensuring good code quality already starts in the developer's IDE. Therefore, for UI components, I already have the following automated pre-commit checks using [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) in my `package.json` where parts of which are already included in the standard SFDX setup:

```
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}": [
      "prettier --write --check"
    ],
    "**/{aura,lwc}/**": [
      "eslint"
    ],
    "**/lwc/**": [
      "sfdx-lwc-jest"
    ]
}
```

Looking for a similar solution as ESLint but for static code analysis for Apex, I still think that [Apex PMD](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-pmd) in Visual Studio Code is the most suitable solution. Now I would like to have this Apex linting checked automatically as well, but I have no approach how to run Apex PMD from the command line to be able to integrate it with lint-staged. However, according to a [statement of the author on GitHub](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/vscode-apex-pmd/issues/83), it should theoretically be possible, even if it focuses primarily on manual checks of the developer in the IDE.

So apart from possible solutions that could be run in an automated pipeline, such as [Sonar](https://www.sonarsource.com/apex/), is there any way to trigger Apex Linting locally via command line or as a pre-commit check?

Answer (score 1):

There's Salesforce's analyzer sfdx plugin.

> The Salesforce Code Analyzer plug-in is a unified tool for static analysis of source code, in multiple languages (including Apex), with a consistent command-line interface and report output.

If you have sfdx and some JDK in your path you could install with:

`sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner`

Note: right now v3 is about to be made default so if it's not yet, i'd use below to install:

`sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest-pilot`

Then run on a target (-t):

`sfdx scanner:run -t /home/jamie/repo/.../force-app/main/default/classes/Rummage.cls`

> Add `--json` to above command to get json output instead of cli text

Command Reference:
https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/v3.x/scanner-commands/run/

Getting Started:
https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/v3.x/getting-started/prerequisites/

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the previous answer, you can simply append a call to the SF CLI Code Analyzer to the `precommit` script.

```
"scripts": {
  "precommit": "lint-staged && sf scanner run --target force-app/ -f table -s 3"
}
```

Setting any severity level will cause a non-zero exit code should a finding appear.

If you just want to scan staged files, create a lint-staged.config.js and include the following:

```
// lint-staged.config.js
module.exports = {
  "**/*.cls": (filenames) => `sf scanner run -f table -s 3 -t ${filenames.join(", ")}`
};
```